# How to consume JSONLD data or JSONLD+Hydra to make hypermedia driven API in Java?

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, json-ld, hydra-core

My question have two parts :
**Part 1)** If Server give data which is JSON-LD then how to consume this JSON-LD? Can we use simple Json Parser?But I don't think it will work because of "@context" which have mapping of every keys.
**Part 2)** Now data is JSON-LD + Hydra( to make Hypermedia driven API) . Assume Hydra part is provided either through API-Documentation like [Markus Lanthaler vocab](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/event-api/vocab) or along with JSON-LD response data.How to get data(properties) and perform action using that data.
I thought  Apache Jena do that job to consume and perform action but still I am not sure , **Is Apache Jena is for this purpose if yes then how is it doing?**

Before answering consider this senario :

```
CLIENT <----via API---> CLIENT HELPER <----via API----> SERVER
```

To communicate with SERVER , CLIENT  will communicate via CLIENT HELPER.

CLIENT HELPER and SERVER both can understand and communicate in JSON-LD.
While CLIENT can understand JSON  only.

In above this scenario , I am implementing CLIENT HELPER(bascially API CLIENT) part how to implement that part.Please explain in layman's term.

Edit 1) :

For this JSON-LD

```
{
  "@context": {
                "@vocab" : "http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/"
              },
  "@id": "http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/1",
  "@type": "User",
  "name": "Dhannan",
  "age": 38,
  "knows" : [
            {
                  "@id": "http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/2",
                  "@type": "User",
                  "name": "Mrigika",
                  "age": 35
            },
            {
                  "@id": "http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/languages/1",
                  "@type": "Language",
                  "description": "English"
            }
    ]
}
```

JAVA Code :

```java
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://data.dummy.jsonld/sampleUser.jsonld");
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
Object input = JsonUtils.fromInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
JsonLdOptions options = new JsonLdOptions();
Object rdf = JsonLdProcessor.toRDF(input,options);
RDFDataset rdfDataset = (RDFDataset) rdf;
System.out.println(rdfDataset);
```

This is the response using [jsonld-java](https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java)

```
{
@default=
    [
        {
        subject={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/1},
        predicate={type=IRI, value=http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type},
        object={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/User}
        },
        {
        subject={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/1},
        predicate={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/age},
        object={type=literal, value=38, datatype=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer}
        },
        {
        subject={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/1},
        predicate={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/knows},
        object={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/2}
        },
        {
        subject={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/1},
        predicate={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/knows},
        object={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/languages/1}
        },
        {
        subject={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/1},
        predicate={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/name},
        object={type=literal, value=Dhannan, datatype=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string}
        },
        {
        subject={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/2},
        predicate={type=IRI, value=http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type},
        object={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/User}
        },
        {
        subject={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/2},
        predicate={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/age},
        object={type=literal, value=35, datatype=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer}
        },
        {
        subject={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/users/2},
        predicate={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/name},
        object={type=literal, value=Mrigika, datatype=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string}
        },
        {
        subject={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/languages/1},
        predicate={type=IRI, value=http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type},
        object={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/Language}
        },
        {
        subject={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/hydra/api/languages/1},
        predicate={type=IRI, value=http://www.myorganisation.com/vocab/description},
        object={type=literal, value=English, datatype=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string}
        }
    ]
}
```

Will I have to deal with this data?

Answer (score 0):

> Part 1) If Server give data which is JSON-LD then how to consume this
>   JSON-LD? Can we use simple Json Parser?But I don't think it will work
>   because of "@context" which have mapping of every keys.

If you know exactly in what form you'll get the data (e.g. because you control the server), you can parse it as JSON. Otherwise, you should rather use a JSON-LD processor to parse it. [json-ld.org](http://json-ld.org/) lists a number of open source implementations.

> Part 2) Now data is JSON-LD + Hydra( to make Hypermedia driven API) .
>   Assume Hydra part is provided either through API-Documentation like
>   Markus Lanthaler vocab or along with JSON-LD response data.How to get
>   data(properties) and perform action using that data. I thought Apache
>   Jena do that job to consume and perform action but still I am not sure
>   , Is Apache Jena is for this purpose if yes then how is it doing?

Every RDF library/tool/framework should be able to help in that regard. There are also more specialized tools. Have a look at [hydra-cg.com](http://www.hydra-cg.com/)

Comment: Please see  Edit:1 of Question.Were you trying convey the same way?.I am still figure out for hydra part ,I will come to hydra part later.